# Javascript quotes ... fade in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good afternoon and happy 4th I've run into issues working on some javascript....I'm a beginner who's using this particular online sample of how to get a fade in and out of multiple quotes...

I've implemented the HTML/the Javascript/the CSS....yet nothing seems to be working out when checking my page using chrome... can someone help me out in terms of what should be changed or other JS examples that may work better?

It always seems like 80% of the Js codes I try fail to appear on my web page....OR is it my HTML or css... blarg! -F

---

```
<....HTML.....JAVASCRIPT......CSS.....order.....>

<h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
<h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>

(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();

.quotes {display: none;}
```

Comment: put your css / javascript in there tags <style>CSS</style> and               <script> javascript<script> , or in external files https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script ,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link,  make sure you have  linked jquery library to your html and putted your code inside $(document).ready() function;

Comment: Osama,  thank you....I have a jquery file and have suceeded with another example however do you mean replace the "(function() {" shown at the beginning of the jv script above with the "$(document).ready()function;" that you have mentioned

Comment: You are welcome, i meant to put all the script content in $(document).ready(function(){ //your code }); , because "(function() {...}())"  is an anonymous function and it should be self invoked.

Answer (score 1):

it works perfectly fine for me , see this link http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/xOApkb

exactly the same

```
(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();
```

Comment: Thanks mina.. using code pen....it works fine...however...when using files files and google chrome...it doesnt seem to work for most javascript coding.  womp womp.  do you know what may the reason for this?  is chrome or the files?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Our Comapny</title>
 <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
    <h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
</head>
<div id="main">
 <h1>Welcome to Our Comapnay</h1>
 <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
 <h2 class="quotes">second quote</h2>
 <h2> Web Site Ingredients:</h2>

 <p>Pages (HTML) </p>
 <p>Style Sheets (CSS)</p>
 <p>Computer Code (JavasScript)</p>
 <p>Live Data (Files and Databases)</p>
 <footer id="foot01"><footer>
</div>
<script src="scriptpractice.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: hey , from the html link above it doesn't look like you're referencing jquery! where did you included jquery js file? if you already did include it do you have errors in the dev tool in browser ? can you attach the error if you have any?

Comment: Hi mina.  using examples ive been able to use jquery...however how do you include the "$(document).ready(function(){"  from the jquery file along with script of another javascript file which uses the particular fading quotes? I'm till getting used to JS and jquery...

Comment: Also tried this: <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

            var quotes = $(".quotes");
            var quoteIndex = -1;

            function showNextQuote() {
            ++quoteIndex;
            quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
            }

            showNextQuote();

            })();​ 

   </script>

Comment: and I receive this at the top "first quote second quoteâ€‹"

Comment: I'm sorry if I am taking too much of your time please skip if its too difficult to follow my explanation. I will keep on sharpening my skills. :)  Thanks again!